# Index values from 2D to 1D array

Tags: python

I have defined a function which searches for the column and row index of the minimum value for a given 2D array (`main_array`). In this case, the minimum value for `main_array` is `1.1`, so index should be `[0,2]`. I then must use the column index value `0` to input into another given 1D array `A_array`, and similarly the row index value `2` into another given 1D array `B_array`, which is the part I am struggling with.

The following is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np

main_array = np.array([[3.1, 2.1, 1.1],
                      [4.1, 1.6, 2.4],
                      [2.2, 3.2, 3.6],
                      [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]])

A_array = np.array([3.7, 4.7, 5.7, 6.7])
B_array = np.array([1.5, 1.8, 2.1])

def min_picks(main_array,A_array,B_array):
    min_index = np.argwhere(main_array == np.min(main_array)) #this gives [[0 2]]
    A_pick = A_array[min_index[0]]
    B_pick = B_array[min_index[-1]]
    return A_pick, B_pick
```

The function should return an expected answer of `A_array[0]` which is assigned to `A_pick`, and `B_array[2]` assigned to `B_pick`.

Comment: Variables and objects' names cannot start with digit, please change them to array_1 or one_array

Comment: I just fixed that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your array index is not correct. Try the following instead:

```
main_array = np.array([[3.1, 2.1, 1.1],
                      [4.1, 1.6, 2.4],
                      [2.2, 3.2, 3.6],
                      [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]])

A_array = np.array([3.7, 4.7, 5.7, 6.7])
B_array = np.array([1.5, 1.8, 2.1])

def min_picks(main_array,A_array,B_array):
    min_index = np.argwhere(main_array == np.min(main_array)) #this gives [[0 2]]
    A_pick = A_array[min_index[:,0]][0]
    B_pick = B_array[min_index[:,1]][0]
    return A_pick, B_pick

>>> min_picks(main_array,A_array,B_array)
#(3.7, 2.1)
```

Comment: I get an output of `(array([3.7]), array([2.1]))`. However, I require an output of `A_array[0]` and `B_array[2]`, rather than the actual values.

Comment: This is not feasible

Comment: If that's the case, is there a way to get an output of just `3.7` and `2.1`, excluding the array parts in `(array([3.7]), array([2.1]))`

Comment: Thank you. Could you also please explain why you added the `[0]` at the end of `A_array[min_index[:,0]][0]` and `B_pick = B_array[min_index[:,1]][0]`? How does `[0]` give just the value? This will help me understand for future codes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to flatten the `min_index` and simply access what you need from that flatten list.

```
from functools import reduce

def min_picks(main_array,A_array,B_array):
    min_index = reduce(lambda z, y :z + y, np.argwhere(main_array == np.min(main_array)))
    A_pick = A_array[min_index[0]]
    B_pick = B_array[min_index[1]]
    return A_pick, B_pick 

print(min_picks(main_array, A_array, B_array))
```

This will give you:

```
(3.7, 2.1)
```